# Menu opacity makes text grey

Tags: html, css

Maybe You know, that I was making Menu on my website....

Now, that menu have `opacity:0.7;`, so the image (background image) behind it is visible... like menu on Apple iMac... Now... I have put some text to menu... and the text is not clearly white... It looks like the text is behind that menu... I tried z-index... But no change..

There is css:

```
.menu {
background-color: black;
opacity:.7;
right: -400px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
width: 400px;
z-index:-10;
}

h1 {
z-index:10;
color:white;
font-size: 50px;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
font-family:Segoe UI Light;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Anybody know how to fix that? Please help me

Comment: For background color use rgba, that way you can set opacity only on the background. E.g. `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);`

Comment: YEAH!!!!!!!!!!

Thanks a lot... rgba helped me!!